# Add/edit an option in an already running instance of lightGallery

Tags: javascript, image, lightbox, lightgallery

Is it possible to add/edit an option in an already running instance of the lightGallery script?
I have this WordPress theme which loads an instance of lightGallery on galleries and I need to add/edit some of its options (for example: change the transition effect between images) without modifying the main theme files (on a child theme, for example).

This is the code found in the theme:

```
var container = $( '.gallery' );
var parseImage = container.data( 'images' );

if ( typeof $.fn.lightGallery != 'undefined' ) {
    container.lightGallery({
        dynamic : true,
        dynamicEl : parseImage
    });
}
```

Can this be done?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for "lightGallery"?

Comment: Yes, I see you can destroy the instance with the destroy() method and reinitialize it with new parameters, but I wanted to know if there's a way to do this without having to destroy the instance first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From their [Pluging API page](https://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/docs/plugin-api.html)

```
    // You can access all lightgallery variables and functions like this.
    this.core = $(element).data('lightGallery');

    this.$el = $(element);
    this.core.s = $.extend({}, defaults, this.core.s)
```

It appears that the `s` property of `$(element).data('lightGallery')` contains all the options. So you can set the mode there. Like this:

```
$(element).data('lightGallery').s.mode = "lg-slide";
```

I tested this in the console on their transitions demo page and it does indeed work.